# ho to ranke records in ssrs groups

Tags: reporting-services, ranking

I have a problem with Ranking in Groups in SSRS

I want to develop a report as below:
[image]

For any record I want to compute a rank based on sum of  3 fields(A+B+c) in its individual Cluster:
And these 3 fields are calculating inn SSRS so I don’t want to add rank in report query.
Has anybody any suggestion about ranking computing in this order?

Answer (score 0):

If each of those sections in colour is generated by a row group, you can use `=RowNumber("RowGroupName")` to give you the row number in that group.